# SQL Convert datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

A existing SQL statement that converts DateTime to a different format has been working for a long time, but is now give me a "Query timeout expired" error only seconds after the query is executed.

```
SQL = "SELECT top 1000000 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TimeStamp,101) + ' ' + 
         CONVERT(CHAR(8),(CONVERT(DATETIME,TimeStamp,113)),114), 
         LogicName, PointValue FROM Trends order by LogicName"
```

Original DateTime is like this: `3/21/2017 6:53:00 PM`

Desired formate is: `03/21/2017 18:53:00`

Is there another/better way to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Please provide the data types of the table fields used in your query.

Comment: Where are you executing the query? What is your connection string? (No password, please) what has recently changed?

Comment: Tried running query with `top 10`? Does that time out too?

Comment: Select top one million... Gee, I wonder why that would be slow.

Comment: Here's a simpler syntax for converting a datetime to that format (but it's comparable in speed): FORMAT(TimeStamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with **"Connection Timeout"** in the configuration of the connection string. Try to set the Connection Timeout parameter value to greater than the current value. (Try to put that value as 60 and check).
Your query --

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 114) AS [Date & Time]
    ,LogicName
    ,PointValue
FROM Trends
ORDER BY LogicName
```

Answer (score 0):

A million DateTime to varchar conversions are going to take a while. First, consider whether the client application can handle the formatting on an as-needed basis, rather than formatting all million+ records in the query.

If the query must supply the TimeStamp value in the specified format, then, for performance, you might want to just add a computed column to the table that stores the TimeStamp value in that format, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Trends
ADD TimeStampFormatted AS FORMAT(TimeStamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Then use this query:

```
SELECT top 1000000 TimeStampFormatted, LogicName, PointValue 
FROM Trends order by LogicName
```

It'll be faster, but it'll require more storage, and it duplicates data, but if speed of retrieval is the most important factor, this is a good bet.